# Angular hide left from specific page

Tags: angularjs

My button code

```
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" 
        ng-click="showMenu()" ng-hide="showLeftMenu"></button>
```

Navigation controller

```
.controller('NavCtrl', ['$http',function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.showMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
  $scope.showRightMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
  };  
  $scope.showLeftMenu = false;
}])
```

I want to hide the left nav from another controller. When it to goes to some specific tabs like contact us.

```
 .controller('ContactTabCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showLeftMenu = true;     
});
```

I tried with even main controller

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showLeftMenu = true;     
})
```

When it goes to contact page, still the left menu values are taken from the main controller not from contact controller

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

if 'MainCtrl' is the parent controller, then in child controllers try using :

```
$scope.$parent.showLeftMenu = false;
```

Comment: .controller('ContactTabCtrl', function($scope) { 
 $scope.$parent.showLeftMenu = false;  
});

i added this code